# How can I generate a unique UUID for all my records on a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, uuid

I have a very simple **MySQL** table that I am querying. However, I would like to return a generated **UUID** for each result row within my query.

I am running the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE(UUID(),'-','') as id, employee_id, store_id FROM employee_store;
```

And I am seeing the results:

```
id                                 employee_id  store_id
617de8d416e711ea91c552540047b61e   123          4
617de8d416e711ea91c552540047b61e   134          3
617de8d416e711ea91c552540047b61e   43           3
617de8d416e711ea91c552540047b61e   333          1
617de8d416e711ea91c552540047b61e   544          2
```

I would have expected all the `id` fields to be different.

**How can I perform the `SELECT` and have the query generate a unique UUID for each result row?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your query in **[this MySQL 5.7 DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1bb82262c175276501b04f6985175be5)**, it gives me:

```
id                               | employee_id | store_id
:------------------------------- | ----------: | -------:
c6c54bdd16e911ea976c00163ec888bf |         123 |        4
c6c54c1e16e911ea976c00163ec888bf |         134 |        3
c6c54c3116e911ea976c00163ec888bf |          43 |        3
c6c54c3f16e911ea976c00163ec888bf |         333 |        1
c6c54c4c16e911ea976c00163ec888bf |         544 |        2
```

If you look closely at the results, you can see that the `UUID`s *are* different. This is easier to see when checking the first 8 characters

```
c6c54bdd
c6c54c1e
c6c54c31
c6c54c3f
c6c54c4c
```

Running the same query in MySQL 5.6 and 8.0, I also get `UUID`s that are slightly different. So I would assume that you do get the same kind of results (unlike what is showned in your sample data).

If you want to generate ids that are more obviously different, you could hash them, as follows:

```
SELECT REPLACE(MD5(UUID()),'-','') as id, employee_id, store_id FROM employee_store;
```

```
id                               | employee_id | store_id
:------------------------------- | ----------: | -------:
e1ae8f1d052c0132d1c111d221acd464 |         123 |        4
91ea4f39657204a4c53ed9f1da53c89b |         134 |        3
9b66fe7957723cf1f581b81d892e798e |          43 |        3
a1240b02775fcc3fca0e1739a27a39fe |         333 |        1
8672b220f28050f9c8680248ded4ccd4 |         544 |        2
```